# Fatal error: Call to undefined function themify_build_write_panels()

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am getting an error when I try to access my site (site on WordPress)
Fatal error: Call to undefined function themify_build_write_panels() in /home/ash/public_html/wp-content/themes/metro/theme- functions.php on line 931

My line 931 is =>

```
themify_build_write_panels( apply_filters(
'themify_theme_meta_boxes' ,
```

please help me!!

Thanks :)

Comment: Soooo you might wanna ask first thing, is that function defined before you are calling it?

Comment: I dont know.. I am a newbie in PHP. Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you did not define this function in functions.php

Check if you properly defined this function or not.

Find this function in your functions.php

```
function themify_build_write_panels(){
    //statements
    //statements       
}
```

You are right you are new to WordPress but as a developer you should know programming and how functions are used in programming and also how to define them.

Error is transparent that you did not define your function.

Comment: I already tried that. I got new error after trying this code»
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/ash/public_html/wp-content/themes/metro/theme-functions.php on line 931

Comment: oh god.. i dont know why you are on earth and also on in programming.. you dont know basic. first of all try to learn basic of programming.
read my answer proper and again again clearly. and then think..
if there are your seniors with you then ask them wht i say in answer..

Comment: I solved that error. But there's a new error- 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function themify_get_data() in /home/ash/public_html/wp-content/themes/metro/theme-functions.php on line 1172

Line 1172 is:

`$data = themify_get_data() ;`

Trying the previous work with this one too..

Comment: i think this your theme has lot of errors. try to download new fresh theme.
the Themefi gives paid themes if you purchased then ask themefi for help. or if you download from torrent or hacking tricks then solve these errors.

Comment: Nop I downloaded from original site. but I dont want to do that. I tried the previous thing I did with this too but doesnt seem to work. Here's the code from line 1170 to line 1172:

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    if ( function_exists ( 'register_sidebar' ) ) {
    $data = themify_get_data();

Any fixes???